# Unity Facebook SDK Login, served with Django encounters CORS/CORB issues on Chrome

Tags: django, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am trying to get a very simple Unity application (Unity Version 2019.4.20f1 Personal) to authenticate with Facebook's SDK for unity. I have set up a local HTTPS server (with self-signed certificates) using Django & Gunicorn (Yes, not ideal, but just trying this out first), which serves the build products of Unity's WebGL.

Here is my one and only script in unity:

```cs
public class FacebookHelper : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Awake function from Unity's MonoBehavior
    void Awake ()
    {
        if (!FB.IsInitialized) {
            // Initialize the Facebook SDK
            FB.Init(InitCallback, OnHideUnity);
        } else {
            // Already initialized, signal an app activation App Event
            FB.ActivateApp();
        }
    }

    private void InitCallback ()
    {
        if (FB.IsInitialized) {
            // Signal an app activation App Event
            FB.ActivateApp();
            // Continue with Facebook SDK
            // ...
        } else {
            Debug.Log("Failed to Initialize the Facebook SDK");
        }
    }

    private void OnHideUnity (bool isGameShown)
    {
        if (!isGameShown) {
            // Pause the game - we will need to hide
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        } else {
            // Resume the game - we're getting focus again
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }

    public void Login() {
        var perms = new List<string>(){"public_profile", "email"};
        FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(perms, this.AuthCallback);
    }

    public void Logout() {
        FB.LogOut();
        Debug.Log("User logged out.");
    }

    public void AuthCallback (ILoginResult result) {

        if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
            // AccessToken class will have session details
            var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
            // Print current access token's User ID
            Debug.Log("UserID: " + aToken.UserId);
            // Print current access token's granted permissions
            foreach (string perm in aToken.Permissions) {
                Debug.Log("Permission: " + perm);
            }
        } else {
            Debug.Log("User cancelled login");
        }
    }
}
```

where the `Login()` and `Logout` functions are called respectively when the two buttons below are pressed:

[image: UI]

**In Chrome, I have two issues:**

1. I am getting CORS and CORB errors, notably only on the `Logout()` action, and not on the `Login` action.
   [image]
2. For the `Login()` action, the Login Dialog is problematic because it opens a new tab as per usual, but it never allows me to input my login details before immediately closing this new tab. For some reason, my logging statements still say that FacebookSDK has successfully logged in.

[image]

**In an attempt to solve this**, I have

1. Enabled CORS on my Django application, according to instructions [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-fix-django-cors-error). Sadly, this didn't work.
2. On the Facebook platform, I have done all these, to no avail as well:

   1. Added `localhost` to the App Domain
   2. Enabled Allow Cross Domain Share Redirects
   3. Added `https://localhost:8080` as the Website
   4. Added `https://localhost:8080` as a valid OAuth redirect uri to the 'Facebook Login for Gaming' Product

**However, in Safari, I met with none of the aforementioned problems.** The login flow works fine.

EDIT:
However, something I encountered on both Chrome and Safari is that for some reason, when the SDK is initialized, it always automatically signs in a default user. For now, I will just add some code to sign out at initialize time to remedy this.

As usual, spent quite a while on this but wasn't able to figure out how I can solve this. According to my understanding, I have to make sure the responses to my server have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, and these may be some ways I think I can do it:

1. Somehow make FacebookSDK set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the response? Maybe their GraphQL API will be more helpful?
2. Use Nginx to reverse proxy and serve the static files instead, and then I should be able to do something like adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header as well. I have thought of doing this but it'll take a bit of investigation, so I haven't tried this yet.

For the CORB issues, I don't really have any ideas though.

I really appreciate it if anyone has taken the time to read up till here, but anyways, thank you to anyone who can help at all! :)

EDIT 1:
Here is the request/response for Safari:

[image]

And here are the request/response for Chrome:

[image]
[image]

The observations I can make is that for some reason Facebook is not returning the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response for the Chrome request. Maybe it is due to the additional headers in the Chrome request?

Comment: CORS and CORB errors for _what_, exactly?

Comment: _“the Login Dialog is problematic because it opens a new tab as per usual, but it never allows me to input my login details before immediately closing this new tab.”_ - if you authorized the app before already, and it is not asking for any additional permissions now, then this is the _expected_ behavior. Users are not supposed to agree to the same stuff over and over again, so if they granted all asked for permissions already, then the login dialog is behaving like this explicitly on purpose.

Comment: Hey, @CBroe updated the question, realized I forgot to attach the error. 

As for your second comment, yup I realized that, so that's why I included the Logout button as well. I guess since I am unable to logout due to the mentioned errors, that's why the Login Dialog never comes to fruition? 

From your question, I also forgot that for some reason when the FB SDK is initialized, it automatically signs a default user already. Not sure about that too, but I've updated the question as such.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Are the URLs really `https://www.facebook.com/x/oauth/…`? That `x/` in there looks weird, if anything, that should be an API version number.

Comment: yup i didn't change the url, just blocked out the token. That's a good point actually, I'll research more on that first, thanks!

Comment: _“when the SDK is initialized, it always automatically signs in a default user”_ - if you initialize the SDK with `status: true`, then it will check if there is a logged-in Facebook user, and if so and that user has logged in to your app before, then it will automatically log that user in again. Set the status to false, if you don’t want that.

Comment: The auto sign-in seems to be disabled now, thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229265/discussion-between-chiah-soon-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a third library or do that in Chrome itself but it's prerence dependent

pip install django-cors-headers

So in Settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
)
```

Or check out his docs for more details https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#setup

Comment: Hey man thanks for replying! Unfortunately, I've tried this, but it didn't work :( Thanks though!

Comment: TTry to combine with this Chrome extension. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf

Comment: Yup i actually tried that too, It kind of works with that but it isn't ideal for my use case. Thanks though!

Comment: I am so confused for our problem but the key when developping mode still in the two approaches tha gave you. Did you realy respect their orders like for middleware. INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
] /.................. Make sure you add the trailing comma or you might get a ModuleNotFoundError (see this blog post).

You will also need to add a middleware class to listen in on responses: See the link or the post. https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/